# Speedometer Android app not working with km/h conversion?

Tags: java, android

I am making a speedometer app for a high school science fair that displays a warning message when a speed is exceeded. When my app hits the speed limit, it does not display the message. However when I change the section `else if (location.getSpeed() >= (EditNum*3.6))` to `else if (location.getSpeed() >= (EditNum))` the app works. The thing is, I don't want to set the limit to MPS. How do I make the app run using the KM/H conversion (*3.6)? PS I am a beginner programmer so sometimes I don't see obvious flaws.

Code:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
TextView war = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
TextView war1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView3); 
TextView war2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView4); 
TextView war3 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
TextView setLimit = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView5);

try{
EditText Edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

String EditValue = Edit.getText().toString();

float EditNum = Float.parseFloat(EditValue);

setLimit.setText("Speed limit: " + (EditNum) + " km/h");


if (location==null)
{
    txt.setText("-.- km/h");
}
else if (location.getSpeed() >= (EditNum*3.6))
{
    war.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
    war.setText("Warning!!!"); 
    war1.setText("Speed limit: " + (EditNum*3.6) + " km/h" );
    war2.setText("Speed: " + (location.getSpeed()*3.6) + " km/h");
    war3.setText("Speed limit exceeded by: " + (EditNum*3.6 - location.getSpeed()) + " km/h");
}
else
{
    float nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
    txt.setText(nCurrentSpeed*3.6 + " km/h");
}
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    nfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: I have not done it since previous changes, will try it now though.

Comment: while debugging, focus on what is the value of location.getSpeed() and what does EditNum*3.6 evaluates into. That will hopefully help you find the answer to your own question.

Comment: EditNum is an EditText (numberDecimal) on the UI that a user can input a speed limit into. The *3.6 is converting the imputed number to km/h.

Comment: So, let's assume, EditNum is 3 and 3.6 will make it, 10.8 so what is the value of location.getSpeed()?

Comment: location.getSpeed() is the current speed in mps that the phone is traveling at.

Comment: So you are trying to compare mps with km/h?

Comment: i dont think so im trying to convert mps to km/h, because the rest of my app is converted

Comment: But you are doing EditNum * 3.6 to convert it into km/h, no?

Comment: Yes that is what im doing

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your strategy isn't working out.  Looking at it quickly, it seems you might need to divide instead of multiply by 3.6.

Don't confuse what you display with what you compute.

I suggest you run your app in debug mode and add break points (red circles in Android Studio) so that you can look at the value your different variables takes at runtime.  You will then understand very easily why certain conditions are met (or not).

Comment: OK, since the phone needs to be moving to achieve a speed, how to I debug while unplugged?

Comment: use a laptop to debug it :D  or insert a scalar (a value) into your program instead of location.getSpeed()

another option, which you probably would prefer, is to display the values in a toast.  That way you can note down what are the values and then analyze it afterwards, without needing to go into debug mode